# Spring Data Rest - How to prevent update of specific fields through PATCH?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am trying to build a RESTful API using Spring Data REST. I have the following domain model defined which consists of a Loan and its Status.

```
public class Loan {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String loanTitle;

    private Double loanAmount;

    private Status status;

}
```

**Status.java**

```
public class Status {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String statusName;

}
```

Now to update the status of a Loan, I am sending a POST request to endpoint `loans/{id}/updateStatus` with the status in the request body. But someone could also update the status using a PATCH request and I dont want that to happen as there are business rules to be applied before updating the status.

So how do I prevent updating the Status object through a PATCH request?

Comment: One way is to define a PATCH resource for status object and reject the request's by providing the reason - Which is very crude way of doing it. Another way is to create an PATCH resource and apply RFC 6902 - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902 or RFC 7396 - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7396 standards and justify why the status object is not allowed to be updated.

Comment: Anotating the field with the Jackson annotation: `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` should prevent updates.

Comment: @AlanHay But that prevents me from setting an initial value for the status on a POST by using RepositoryEventHandler. So the status will always be null.

Comment: Why? It prevents JSON binding but you can do whatever you want after that. Why would it prevent manually setting?

Comment: I just found out I didnt have `@Component` annotation on the event handler. I thought it wasnt required since I had `@RepositoryEventHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking around for the solution to this problem, and I've found something that works well.

Simply override the setter in the model, and ensure that the underlying property is null before allowing a new value to be set.

Example code works with both merge and json-patch PATCH types, but is Kotlin (sorry)

```
var uuid: String? = null
    set(uuid) {
        if (field == null) {
            field = uuid
        }
    }
```